# MathJax & Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input, mathjax

I am trying to receive text inputs with HTML when dealing with fractions and alignment of equations in MathJax. When I do this, the math typography doesn't work (as shown below). Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<html>
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  }
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
</script>
Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{3}$.</br>
Then, 
$f(9)=\frac{<input type="text" size="3">}{3}=3$.</br></br> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax won't process mathematics that contains HTML tags (other than `<br>` and comments), so you are right that what you have done is not going to work.  But there is a loophole that can be used to get input fields, as discussed in [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/Udj9oD9uyU8/m/P3D3NkEGAwAJ) that uses the MathML `<semantics>` tag to get HTML into the expression.

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['input']}},
  startup: {
    ready() {
      const Configuration = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration.Configuration;
      const CommandMap = MathJax._.input.tex.SymbolMap.CommandMap;
      const TEXCLASS = MathJax._.core.MmlTree.MmlNode.TEXCLASS;
      
      new CommandMap('input', {input: 'Input'}, {
        Input(parser, name) {
          const xml = parser.create('node', 'XML');
          const id = parser.GetBrackets(name, '');
          const w = parser.GetBrackets(name, '5em');
          const value = parser.GetArgument(name);
          xml.setXML(MathJax.startup.adaptor.node('input', {
            id: id, value: value, style: {width: w}, xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
          }), MathJax.startup.adaptor);
          xml.getSerializedXML = function () {
            return this.adaptor.outerHTML(this.xml) + '</input>';
          }
          parser.Push(
            parser.create('node', 'TeXAtom', [
              parser.create('node', 'semantics', [
                parser.create('node', 'annotation-xml', [
                  xml
                ], {encoding: 'application/xhtml+xml'})
              ])
            ], {texClass: TEXCLASS.ORD})
          );
        }
      });
      Configuration.create('input', {handler: {macro: ['input']}});

      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
};
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>

$$ \int_{\input[sub][1em]{0}}^{\input[sup][1em]{1}} \input[integrand][10em]{}\, dx$$
```

This could be made into a formal extension, if you will be using it often.

Comment: Hello, is there anyway to realise the function above with MathJax 2.7.7? Thanks.