# MathJax: Input & Trigger Button Event

Tags: javascript, html, input, mathjax, mathml

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447944/mathjax-inputs) shows how to essentially create an HTML input within a math equations that is compatible with MathJax.  For example, `$$3+3=\input[q1][1em]{}$$` would be essentially equivalent to typing `$$3+3=$$<input type="text" id="q1" />` in HTML.

I do not understand why a trigger button event on the return key does not work for the `\input[q1][1em]{}` way. It does work using the second basic HTML way.

Below is an example of the event failing to trigger when clicking return. How can I get it to trigger where the input is embedded within the equation as such? Any help would be very much appreciated!

```html
<html>
   <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['input']}},
      startup: {
        ready() {
          const Configuration = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration.Configuration;
          const CommandMap = MathJax._.input.tex.SymbolMap.CommandMap;
          const TEXCLASS = MathJax._.core.MmlTree.MmlNode.TEXCLASS;
          
          new CommandMap('input', {input: 'Input'}, {
            Input(parser, name) {
              const xml = parser.create('node', 'XML');
              const id = parser.GetBrackets(name, '');
              const w = parser.GetBrackets(name, '5em');
              const value = parser.GetArgument(name);
              xml.setXML(MathJax.startup.adaptor.node('input', {
                id: id, value: value, style: {width: w}, xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
              }), MathJax.startup.adaptor);
              xml.getSerializedXML = function () {
                return this.adaptor.outerHTML(this.xml) + '</input>';
              }
              parser.Push(
                parser.create('node', 'TeXAtom', [
                  parser.create('node', 'semantics', [
                    parser.create('node', 'annotation-xml', [
                      xml
                    ], {encoding: 'application/xhtml+xml'})
                  ])
                ], {texClass: TEXCLASS.ORD})
              );
            }
          });
          Configuration.create('input', {handler: {macro: ['input']}});

          MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<!------------- Document Starts Here ------------->
    $$3+3= \input[q1][1em]{}$$
<button id="myBtn" onclick="javascript:alert('You have submitted this question.')">BUTTON</button>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("q1");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
</script>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Note there are some error messages when running on the code on this site but it should be compatible running it elsewhere.